# Issue With C# Oracle Procedure Call

Tags: c#, oracle, .net-4.0

looking for some help in identifying the correct method of calling an Oracle Procedure call from the given info below. I am using .NET 4 with Oracle.DataAccess.Client.
Below are the details of the Procedure from Oracle:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE APPS.syk_serial_num_details
AS
TYPE account_rec_type IS RECORD(
  inv_item_id                   NUMBER
 ,item_num                      VARCHAR2(40)
 ,item_desc                     VARCHAR2(240)
 ,acc_num                       VARCHAR2(30)
 ,ship_to                       VARCHAR2(1000)
 ,bill_to                       VARCHAR2(1000)
);

TYPE account_set IS TABLE OF account_rec_type; 

 PROCEDURE get_prod_details(
  p_serial_num               IN       VARCHAR2
 ,p_acc_nums                 IN       VARCHAR2
 ,p_ship_tos                 IN       VARCHAR2
 ,p_acc_set                  OUT      syk_serial_num_details.account_set
 ,p_status                   OUT      VARCHAR2
 );

END syk_serial_num_details
```

here are some more details showing the param types and size...below is an example of the procedure call from Toad interface:

```
DECLARE
l_serial_num                  csi_item_instances.serial_number%type;
l_acc_nums                    VARCHAR2(100);
l_ship_tos                    VARCHAR2(100);
l_acc_set  syk_serial_num_details.account_set;
l_status                      VARCHAR2(80);

BEGIN

   l_serial_num               :=  '1025200453';
   l_acc_nums                 := '8165';
   l_ship_tos                 := '10332';
   l_acc_set := syk_serial_num_details.account_set();
   syk_serial_num_details.get_prod_details(p_serial_num                  => l_serial_num
                                          ,p_acc_nums                    => l_acc_nums
                                          ,p_ship_tos                    => l_ship_tos
                                          ,p_acc_set                     => l_acc_set
                                          ,p_status                      => l_status
                                          );


   Dbms_output.put_line('Status ::' || l_status);
   IF(l_acc_set.count >0) then
   FOR i IN 1 .. l_acc_set.count
   LOOP
   l_acc_set.extend;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(   'Item_Number:'
                           || l_acc_set(i).item_num||'|'
                           || '   Desc:'
                           || l_acc_set(i).item_desc||'|'
                           || '   Accunt Number:'
                           || l_acc_set(i).acc_num||'|'
                           || '   Ship To:'
                           || l_acc_set(i).ship_to||'|'
                           || '   Bill To:'
                           || l_acc_set(i).bill_to||'|'
                          );
   END LOOP;
   end if;

END;
```

So...I am having LOTS of trouble trying to identify the proper type for the p_acc_set output.
Below is my current C# code:

```
        OracleConnection conn = getOracleConnection();
        List<AccountSearchResultsDto> ProductInfoList = new List<AccountSearchResultsDto>();
        using (conn)
        {
            conn.Open();

            using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("syk_serial_num_details.get_prod_details", conn))
            {

                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                //ASSIGN PARAMETERS TO BE PASSED 
                OracleParameter param1 = new OracleParameter("p_serial_num", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
                param1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                param1.Size = 100;
                param1.Value = "1025200453";
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param1);

                OracleParameter param2 = new OracleParameter("p_acc_nums", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
                param2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                param2.Size = 100;
                param2.Value = "8165";
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param2);

                OracleParameter param3 = new OracleParameter("p_ship_tos", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
                param3.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                param3.Size = 100;
                param3.Value = "10332";
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param3); 


                //PARAMETERS USED TO RETURN RESULT OF PROCEDURE CALL 
                OracleParameter param4 = new OracleParameter("p_acc_set", OracleDbType.Object);
                param4.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                param4.Size = 1;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param4);

                OracleParameter param5 = new OracleParameter("p_status", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
                param5.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                param5.Size = 300;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param5); 


                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                if (cmd.Parameters["p_status"].Value.ToString().Equals("SUCCESS"))
                {
                       //Get results from p_acct_set and put values in list
                }



            }
        }
```

As of now - attempting the above I am getting the following error:

> Invalid parameter binding
>   Parameter name: p_acc_set

Should i be using the OracleParameter UdtTypeName reference for the p_acc_set?

I am very new to Oracle Procedure calls so please forgive my inexperience. 
Any help is appreciated! thanks in advance!!

-R

Answer (score 0):

The difference i spotted for parameter "p_acc_set" and "p_status" compare to others is that they did not assign Size on them please try to assign size on them and should fix your issue

I did not find the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracleparameter.size.aspx) explaining very clearly on OracleParamter.Size property. But i did notice a line in the remarks that says

> **The line is taken from MSDN remarks :**
>
> For bidirectional and output parameters, and return values, you must
>   set the value of Size.

Comment: No. Read the OP and take look at SP.

Comment: @AVD your right I have updated my answer and thank you for correction

Comment: This error looks like to me you are passing incorrect number or type of parameters to your stored procedure called GET_PROD_DETAILS. You should raise this as a separate question mate

Comment: @RustyMorton i wasn't being rude I am just trying to keep the comments trail smaller

Comment: ok, was about to create a new question, then i realized there was a problem in the way i applied the size. i fixed that and I am still getting the same error.
I updated my code to reflect the addtion of the size attribute

Comment: Can you please show me you stored proc params with size and type

Comment: @HatSoft I added more details showing an example of the call using TOAD. Thanks again for continuing to help!

Answer (score 0):

There's the property [BindByName](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e23174/OracleCommandClass.htm#i997666) of OracleCommand class (**defaulted to false**) to handle this.

**You should set it to true** before executing the command to avoid that error!

for further informations read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e23174/toc.htm) too!!

Edit

Sorry, I didn't notice there was a PL/SQL Nested Table!! I don't think that Oracle supports a bind for that (especially if it contains records instead of simple values).

Associative Arrays, PL/SQL Nested tables and PL/SQL Vararrays are very similar data types so probably [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e23174/featOraCommand.htm#BABBDHBB) they intend all the three things with the name Associative Arrays.

Using a Nested Table of User defined Types in place of it should solve your problem but it will become very trivial to handle for a newbie ...If so you should redefine the procedure to use the new data type and setting UdtTypeName parameter in the C# code is not the only thing to do.

Comment: tried setting
cmd.BindByName = true;
Still getting same error "Invalid parameter binding Parameter name: p_acc_set"

Comment: I edited my answer I supposed that the error message was referring a simpler problem.

Comment: @Allessandro thanks for the clarificaion. I can possibly influence the Oracle team to modify the procedure call to make it easier on the web front end. Unless anyone else pipes in with a better solution in the next few days I will try that route and have them change the Record type to a table of UDTs.